Flutter project causes build failed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':rive_common:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: ninja: Entering directory `C:\Users\Eng-Loay\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\rive_common-0.4.7\android.cxx\Debug\4c5t6619\arm64-v8a'
[1/1] Linking CXX shared library C:\Users\Eng-Loay\StudioProjects\red_fin\build\rive_common\intermediates\cxx\Debug\4c5t6619\obj\arm64-v8a\librive_text.so
FAILED: C:/Users/Eng-Loay/StudioProjects/red_fin/build/rive_common/intermediates/cxx/Debug/4c5t6619/obj/arm64-v8a/librive_text.so
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\Eng-Loay\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\25.1.8937393\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe --target=aarch64-none-linux-android21 --sysroot=C:/Users/Eng-Loay/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -DWITH_RIVE_TEXT -DWITH_RIVE_AUDIO_TOOLS -DWITH_RIVE_AUDIO -DMA_NO_RESOURCE_MANAGER -DHAVE_OT -DHB_NO_FALLBACK_SHAPE -DHB_NO_WIN1256 -DHB_NO_EXTERN_HELPERS -DHB_NO_CFF -DHB_NO_BUFFER_VERIFY -DHB_NO_BUFFER_MESSAGE -DHB_NO_PAINT -DHB_NO_MMAP -DHB_NO_META -DYOGA_EXPORT= -std=c++11 -fno-limit-debug-info  -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,--no-rosegment -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -shared -Wl,-soname,librive_text.so -o C:\Users\Eng-Loay\StudioProjects\red_fin\build\rive_common\intermediates\cxx\Debug\4c5t6619\obj\arm64-v8a\librive_text.so @CMakeFiles\rive_text.rsp  && cd ."
ld: error: undefined hidden symbol: OT::cff2::accelerator_t::get_extents(hb_font_t*, unsigned int, hb_glyph_extents_t*) const


referenced by hb-subset-plan.cc:1019 (C:/Users/Eng-Loay/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/rive_common-0.4.7/ios/harfbuzz/src/hb-subset-plan.cc:1019)
CMakeFiles/rive_text.dir/cc8a84f55c69d24d54265afd29fab699/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/rive_common-0.4.7/ios/harfbuzz/src/hb-subset-plan.cc.o:(_update_instance_metrics_map_from_cff2(hb_subset_plan_t*))
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.


C++ build system [build] failed while executing:
@echo off
"C:\Users\Eng-Loay\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\cmake\3.18.1\bin\ninja.exe" ^
-C ^
"C:\Users\Eng-Loay\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\rive_common-0.4.7\android\.cxx\Debug\4c5t6619\arm64-v8a" ^
rive_text
from C:\Users\Eng-Loay\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\rive_common-0.4.7\android
Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 17s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I tried to check version of awesome_dialog: ^3.1.0 but it doesn't work

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
